# Adding a if.....else in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to apply an if condition to each element of vectors in R, but seems that I am doing something wrong:

```
nobjects <- length(EMATRSTDV)
for (i in 1:nobjects) {
 if (MPEMAPlusDemiTR - EMATRSTDV > Cl(myData$AAPL)){
 ShortLevel <- MPEMAPlusDemiTR - EMATRSTDV
 } else {
 ShortLevel <- "..."
 }
}
```

I am getting the error message:

> Error in if (MPEMAPlusDemiTR - EMATRSTDV > Cl(myData$AAPL)) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (MPEMAPlusDemiTR - EMATRSTDV > Cl(myData$AAPL)) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: What is `Cl(myData$AAPL)`?

Comment: It is the closing price of AAPL vector actually. Obtained using : getSymbols(mySymbols, env = myData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate, to = endDate)
head(myData$AAPL)

Comment: you're not using `i` are you ?...

Comment: oh dear, i just realise,...i am completely blocked then

Answer (score 0):

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

well, from the error message and from the code where you compute `length(EMATRSTDV)` it is obvious that `EMATRSTDV` is a vector. In condition you have to use indexed value

```
for (i in 1:nobjects) {
    if (MPEMAPlusDemiTR - EMATRSTDV[i] > Cl(myData$AAPL)){
        ShortLevel[i] <- MPEMAPlusDemiTR - EMATRSTDV[i]
    } else {
        ShortLevel[i] <- "..."
    }
}
```